How to create Single Select Menu with items under the menu (not a pop-up) in Flutter
I want to create a button that opens a menu to select an item . But I want the menu not to be a pop-up but builds under the Button.See design for referece.
Is there a Library that does this? Or should I programm it from sratch?
There is Widgets like "DropdownButton2" and "DropdownButton" that show the widget Menu as a pop-up. I want the same thing but it shows the elements in a menu built under the button and takes space and does not cover other elements under the menu , like the design.

You can see in this design that the menu is not a pop-up.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a popular library that does this. This design can be implemented using ExpansionTile — it turns out it's easier to use ExpansionTile than ExpansionPanel since the latter must be used with ExpansionPanelList, which isn't easy to customize outside of the default Material design.
Here's an example implementation that sticks as close as possible to your design and that you can change to suit your needs.
class ExpandingMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> menuOptions;

  const ExpandingMenu({super.key, required this.menuOptions});

  @override
  State<ExpandingMenu> createState() => _ExpandingMenuState();
}

class _ExpandingMenuState extends State<ExpandingMenu> {
  String? _selectedOption;
  final _controller = ExpansionTileController();
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final outlineColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outlineVariant;

    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        // This is required to remove the default dividers around the
        // ExpansionTile
        dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        showTrailingIcon: false,
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        controller: _controller,
        onExpansionChanged: (value) => setState(() => _isExpanded = value),
        title: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: _isExpanded ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : outlineColor,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                _selectedOption ?? 'Vorlage aussuchen',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: (_isExpanded || _selectedOption != null)
                      ? Colors.black
                      : Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Transform.rotate(
                angle: pi / 2,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.chevron_right_rounded,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              border: Border.all(
                color: outlineColor,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                for (String option in widget.menuOptions)
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                      _selectedOption = option;
                      _controller.collapse();
                    }),
                    child: Text(
                      option,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ].expand((e) => [e, const Divider(height: 20)]).toList()
                ..removeLast(), // Remove the trailing divider
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

And in your case:
ExpandingMenu(
  menuOptions: ['keine Auswahl', 'Vorlage 1', 'Vorlage 2'],
)

Result


Most libraries that I have seen popup over other content, so you probably need to build something from scratch.
It shouldn't be too hard to build something like this though. Either you can build a custom Widget that shows/hides the content, or you could put these options in an ExpansionPanel
